# Emacs keyboard changed

Tags: emacs, keyboard

Several times now while programming in Emacs my keyboard has started to write Greek letters into the buffer.  I assumed that I'd pressed some key combination but after searching I've yet to figure out what it is and my only solution right now is to restart Emacs.  So what am I doing and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you check the value of your `current-input-method`? I'm shooting in the dark here but I'm guessing you've changed it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb.

You're working on a windows computer that has multiple input languages configured (including greek). It also has the default keyboard shortcut to switch between them enabled (left alt+shift is the default, and if you have multiple inputs set up, it is on by default).

Some emacs shortcuts require an alt-shift combo, and depending on the order you press them, you get or don't get windows intercepting it for the IME switch.

Possible solutions include:

- remove the greek IME
- disable the windows shortcut to switch IMEs
- change said shortcut

I typically want multiple IMEs on my systems, like that I can switch IMEs quickly, and don't want to mess with default shortcuts, so I ended up getting used to always pressing shift *then* alt when doing alt-shift combos in emacs.

Comment: That's the problem, a year or two ago I set up my keyboard to be able to switch to Greek characters and I just never really used it, and after a while I forgot about it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to analyse what you've pressed.

`M-x list-command-history`  shows command history

`C-h l` runs the command `view-lossage` which displays last 300 input keystrokes